# How to judge a TypeElement or TypeMirror is subClass of other one?

Tags: java, android, annotations, apt

I have two class.

```
Class A<T>{
}

Class B extend A<String>{
}
```

I want to judge if TypeElement of B is subclass of A ?
So i try,

```
TypeElement elementA = A.getElement();
TypeElement elementB = B.getElement();

processingEnv.getTypeUtils().isAssignable(elementB.asType(),elementA.asType())//return false(i think it show return true)
processingEnv.getTypeUtils().isSubtype(elementB.asType(),elementA.asType())//return false(i think it show return true)
```

Comment: What is `getElement()`?

Comment: @ajb It mean get the typeElement of Class A,in fact,it don't exist.